# TFS connection using Azure Active Directory account

Tags: tfs, active-directory

So for years I've been logging into my PC using a basic Windows Live account and then using RUNAS.exe to use my AD account when launching Visual Studio and SSMS and everything worked ok.  I decided to move to an AD login on my laptop so that I don't need to do the RUNAS.exe for anything I want to use my AD credentials.

Got my user setup fine, and SSMS works without a hitch.  The problem is TFS and the Security Device Credential PIN.  My org has it set that I have to set a Windows Hello PIN when setting up.  If I login to my laptop using that option, I basically can't connect to TFS.  If I use my password, I have better luck.

If I use Edge to browse to my TFS server, I'm prompted for a login and by default it asks for my Security Device Credential (PIN).  It accepts it, but Edge cannot connect to the site.  If I launch and using 'Other Options' and retype my account and password, it works no problem.

This is crazy.  Any ideas why this would be this way?  I've looked and cannot find any answers on this.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: What error did you get when you connect to TFS?

Comment: I actually get the page on Edge showing..
"Hmmmm....can't reach this page", like I'm not connected to the internet.  But if I use the same account and password, works no problem.

Comment: Anybody??  Can't believe I'm the only one who's had this issue.